# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type array, null given .. Error to post data

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, vue.js, controller

I am getting error saying create() must be array in my store function. I am litte confuse how to change it/correct this error. Anyone could suggest me ? I am using vue js. I used formdata append and  axios to post the data in database.

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $requestJob = $request->get('UserApplyJob');
        $requestJob = UserApplyJob::create($requestJob);
    }
```

data function

```
data(){
            return{
                UserApplyJob:{
                    name:"",
                    email:"",
                    telephone:"",
                    pitch:"",
                    expectedSalary:"",
                    resume: null 
                },
                error:{}            
            }
```

this is the method function

```
 methods:{
            validate: function(){
                let valid = true;

                if (!this.UserApplyJob.name){
                    this.$set(this.error, 'name' , 'Name is required');
                    valid=false;
                }
                return valid;
            },
            getFile(event){
                this.UserApplyJob.resume = event.target.files[0];
            },
            submit(){

                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('name',this.UserApplyJob.name);
                formData.append('email',this.UserApplyJob.email);
                formData.append('expectedSalary',this.UserApplyJob.expectedSalary);
                formData.append('pitch',this.UserApplyJob.pitch);
                formData.append('telephone',this.UserApplyJob.telephone);
                formData.append('resume',this.UserApplyJob.resume);

                axios({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/applyJob',
                    data: formData,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
                })
                .then(function (response) {

                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function (response) {
                    //handle error
                    console.log(response);
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change to:

```
$requestJob = $request->all();
$requestJob = UserApplyJob::create($requestJob);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in `store` controller method is using the form field which it doesn't have (`formData` doesn't have any UserApplyJob field).

I suppose you want to create `UserApplyJob` model with the `formData`. For that you would need to use all the request data:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $requestJob = UserApplyJob::create($request->all());
}
```